# Bash autocomplete paths "through" environmental variables

Tags: bash, debian, path, autocomplete

I used to be able to type

```
cd $home/p
```

hit the tab key and the command would change to

```
cd /home/phill
```

Now it doesn't. When cd'ing to a directory based on an environmental variable, I'm "flying blind" now which is annoying. I know this feature exists because it was fine on my old Debian 5 machine.

I'm using Debian 6 stable. I installed the bash completion package which allows  to complete partial environmental variables but that isn't what I want. Unfortunately talk of that feature is clogging up results on Google.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just diffed my two bash_rc files. Turns out I need to *delete* the section that sources /etc/bash_completion, that is, to NOT use bash_completion extensions.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work w/o needing to disable all the useful completions provided by /etc/bash_completion?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I think that requires a fresh post.