# Is there a resolution to autocomplete in bash escaping export variables?

Tags: bash, unix, autocomplete

Export variables in bash are now escaped with auto-completion (tab). A change linked to in another post here at [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/289898/bash-autocomplete-paths-through-environmental-variables). Is there any change to this issue?

Comment: It is not clear to me what your problem is. Do you want completion of environment variables or not? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I upgraded from F11 to F15. It was a surprise to me that the new bash now escapes an exported variable's '$' character by default. Thus, borking the use of tab to complete a dir/file name, requiring the arrow key to navigate to the \ character to remove it. (>_<)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to this [issue](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00274.html) reported on bug-bash for which there is a patch which [is on its way to popular Linux distros](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-06/msg00064.html).